# regex condicional en base a una cadena

Tags: regex

soy medio nuevo con expresiones regulares así que quizás alguien pueda orientarme.
estoy usando un regex que encuentra un string entre 2 ´_´ y remplaza los mismo y envuelve el string con etiquetas ´´. Me gustaría agregar una condición en el regex para que haga este remplazo solo si la cadena tiene un espacio antes del primer ´_´ o uno al final, ya que no quiero que se envuelva en etiquetas cuando esta en una url (dejo un ejemplo)

```js
let text = "Texto ejemplo www.ejemplo.com/pag_sig_link  url: https://www.keego.app/ _hola_"    
let newText = text.replace(/(?:_)([^_]*)(?:_)/gm, "<i>$1</i>");
console.log(newText)
```

Comment: Quieres envolver en etiquetas el texto que no sea una URL y que esté dentro de guiones bajos. Es correcto?

Comment: Hola @Jhon disculpa la demora, es correcto, gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder, estuve probando tu solución pero hay casos en los que me envuelve mas de lo que deberia con la etiqueta, por ejemplo en este caso: "_prueba  texto_ Texto ejemplo www.ejemplo.com/pag_sig_link  url: https://www.keego.app/ _hola_ chau", el retorno ideal seria: "<h1>prueba  texto</h1> Texto ejemplo www.ejemplo.com/pag_sig_link  url: https://www.keego.app/ <h1>hola</h1>_ chau" pero me envuelve desde el inico hasta "_chau".

Answer (score 0):

Creo esto es lo que buscas, espero te ayude.

```js
const regexp = /(\s_.+_)|(_.+_\s)/;
const text = "Texto ejemplo www.ejemplo.com/pag_sig_link  url: https://www.keego.app/ _hola_";


const newText = text.replace(regexp, result => {
  return ` <h1>${result}</h1>`
})

console.log(newText);
document.body.innerText = newText;
```